# angular2 instantiate a service

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I call a service from my component like this:

```
import { MissionService } from './modal.service';
```

I inject it in the constructor:

```
model: any = {};
constructor(private modalService: NgbModal,
            private missionService: MissionService) {}
open(content) {  
    this.model = this.missionService.getCompany();
...
}
```

When I modify `this.model`using a form, the `this.missionService.getCompany()` change also.
I want to modify `this.model` without changing the object `this.missionService.getCompany()`

Comment: Then create a copy of the company.

Comment: can u give me an example please !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39833288/cloning-a-typescript-object

Comment: I want to clone object (without using jQuery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :

```
this.model = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.missionService.getCompany()));
```